# Configuring Track & Plan service thru API

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

We are looking for the relevant API's which we can use to configure the Track & Plan service by calling the API's rather than manual configuration via UI.

Request you to kindly confirm if the Track & Plan service can be configured using API's and if yes, please provide us the link/source where we can look for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current Track & Plan is running a limited version of RTC and there are no open APIs for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The track and plan service is based on Rational Team Concert. Many of the APIs for RTC (see http://jazz.net) can be used.

The track and plan service is limited though in its ability to be customized and those limitations are enforced even through API.